# Check if username already exists in database using linq

Tags: c#, linq

What would be the linq query to check if the username already exists in database?
Say my table name is "DeskOperators"
and I have the column name "Username"

Answer (score 6):

You can use [Enumerable.Any](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.any.aspx). It will return true of any of record has user name you are looking for.

```
DeskOperators.Any(r=>r.Username == userName)
```

You can use [Enumerable.Single](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb155325.aspx) or [Enumerable.SingleOrDefault](http://Enumerable.SingleOrDefault) to ensure that only one record match the condition.

Comment: I suspect you actually mean `Queryable.Any(Expression<Func<T, bool>>)`

Answer (score 1):

```
   var result = (from row in DeskOperators 
                          where row.Username== txtUsername.Text.ToString()
                          select row).ToList();

if (result.Count() != 0)
            {
                lblmsg1.Visible = true;
                lblmsg.Text = "User Name is Already Exist";

            }
            else
            {
               //your code.

            }
```

try with this one.

Answer (score 0):

This will select the first username that matches but won't throw an exception if none is found  (you just end up with a blank set).

```
var i = (from c in DeskOperators 
   where c.Username == CodeHugger 
   select c.CustomerID).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

like this

```
 if (!dbcontex.table.Any(s => s.column == value))
```

Answer (score 0):

I have have written the following code to register user. I am checking if the username already exists. I tried the following and it worked for me:

```
var checkexistance = (from reg in db.RegisterOperatorTables  where reg.OperatorName == operatorModel.OperatorName select reg);
            if (checkexistance.Count()>0)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                table.OperatorName = operatorModel.OperatorName;
                table.OperatorPassword = operatorModel.Password;
                db.RegisterOperatorTables.InsertOnSubmit(table);
                db.SubmitChanges();

                return true;
            }
```